# How to restart proFTPD on a Fedora server with Plesk

Tags: ftp, fedora, proftpd, plesk

I need to do this through the command line (SSH). Tried:

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd restart
service ftpd restart
service proftpd restart
/usr/sbin/proftpd restart
```

They all show unrecognised or invalid option errors.

Answer (score 3):

It runs under xinetd in plesk

```
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

that should restart it

Comment: Will that restart the whole web stack though? I'm slightly nervous about doing that because it hasn't been touched in a couple of yearrs.

Comment: ok then,
Have a look in /etc/xinet.d/ftp_psa for details on what it is calling

Comment: That file doesn't exist, could it have a different name?

Comment: if you look in /etc/xinetd.conf, that should show you what directory it is looking in for starting services. One of them should be ftp like.